# Building a loop in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

i'm new to Ocaml and i got an issue with a simple loop, here is my code :

```
    open Str;;

let main () =
let quit_loop = ref false in
  while not !quit_loop do
    let str = read_line () in
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "create") str 0
      then let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
      print_string "List created\n";
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "delete") str 0
      then let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
      print_string "train deleted\n";
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "quit") str 0
      then quit_loop := true

done;;

let _ = main ()
```

The code compile but it seem that only "create" work. If you have any tips to help me...

Thanks !

Comment: My hunch is that all subsequent `if`s are nested within the first `if`. Does anything change if you put parens around the `if` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you indented it properly you would have obtained this :

```
open Str;;

let main () =
  let quit_loop = ref false in
  while not !quit_loop do
    let str = read_line () in
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "create") str 0
    then let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
      print_string "List created\n";
      if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "delete") str 0
      then let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
        print_string "train deleted\n";
        if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "quit") str 0
        then quit_loop := true

  done;;

let _ = main ()
```

As you can see, the other `if` are nested in the first `if` block. This is due to the `let e = ... in instr1; ...` that creates a block containing everything that will follow.

You should write (*you can replace `begin ... end` by `(...)`*) :

```
open Str;;

let main () =
  let quit_loop = ref false in
  while not !quit_loop do
    let str = read_line () in
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "create") str 0
    then begin 
      let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
      print_string "List created\n"
    end;
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "delete") str 0
    then begin 
      let train_list = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t]+") str in
      print_string "train deleted\n"
    end;
    if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "quit") str 0
    then quit_loop := true
  done;;

let _ = main ()
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help !